# I was given android and iOS SDK from the manufacturer. However I only know a little bit of Flutter. Is there anyway I can use Flutter to run this app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sdk

I bought an ip camera from alibaba and I was told by the manufacturer that I can develop my own app utilizing the provided SDK. What they provided me was the native android and iOS SDK for this ip camera. However, I do not know how to use both of them and only know a little about Flutter development. Is there any way I can use Flutter to try out the SDK? This SDK seems like a basic demo app for this ipcamera

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Tester! Do you have some kind of protocol describing how can an app communicate with the camera? Or can you extrapolate the code regarding the data exchange with the camera from the demo app?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @il_boga I actually do not know the protocol that the app is using to communicate with the camera. In fact, there is little to no documentation on how to use the SDK. As for the code extrapolation, I am afraid I don't know enough Java to even understand those.

Comment: Then I fear that either you have to find on internet the protocol related to that camera model, or you'll be forced to understand the Java included in their SDK. I mean, unless there's an easy way to inlcude custom Java code in the scripts Flutter uses to build the apps...but that is out of my experience, for now I'm limited to pure dart/flutter without going deeper in the platform-specific development part.

Comment: Ya that sounds about right. I will try to learn Java and see how far it can bring me. Thanks for your advice.